# Trying to get Orange connected to Postgres Database

Tags: orange, databases

I recently came across [Orange](https://orange.biolab.si/), and am very keen to try it for our company's purposes (around 20 potential users, perhaps more). I have installed Orange (latest version) and am trying to connect to our database, as it has a large (multi GB) database of telemetry collected from the sawmill.

However I am unable to connect. I have installed psycopg2 as instructed, but when I try to connect, I get a message saying "Could not open Extension file" ... Apparently a tsm_system_time.control file is missing. And it indeed is not in the folder as directed by psycopg2, I have looked.

I have an IT specialist friend, who tried installing Orange on his laptop (he also has a postgres database on it) and he got the same message, except he apparently was missing a quantile.control file. He didn't proceed further, but I am, wondering

1. What are all these "missing" .control files, and
2. Why does psycopg2 need them if they are not pertinent to database operation (everything else works in the database, including reporting etc.)
3. How do I resolve the problem? No help forthcoming online in terms of missing .control files.

I'm running on Windows 7 (Database is a local server running Windows 2012 Server)

Answer (score 2):

To install [tsm_system_time](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tsm-system-time.html) you need the [contrib](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib.html) package installed too, see instructions on that page (or [this page](https://github.com/biolab/orange3/wiki/Installation-of-PostgreSQL-extensions)).

These are various extensions that are not needed for basic database operations but are useful for certain applications, this is apparently such a use case. The control file is like a script that tells Postgres how to install each extension when it encounters the `CREATE EXTENSION` command.